# INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE when calling CreateFileA several times

Tags: c++, c, file-io, port

I'm using CreateFileA and the first time I call it, it works as expected. But when i call it the second time, it returns handle INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE. What could be the problem? Just for information, I'm calling it every time I need to check if my USB device is connected..

```
int port = 500;
char port_name [MAX_CAR] = {0};

sprintf_s (port_name, MAX_CAR, "\\\\.\\COM%d", port);

com->id = CreateFileA (port_name,
                       GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                       0,
                       NULL,
                       OPEN_EXISTING,
                       FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                       NULL);
```

EDIT: I did try to use CloseHandle like CloseHandle(com->id); but it doesn't help.

Comment: You are exceeding the max open file handles. Make sure you close the handles after use to void.

Comment: You are blind as a bat as long as you don't add proper error reporting.  Using GetLastError() is never optional when you tinker with serial ports, far too many things can go wrong that are beyond your control.

Comment: Is your CloseHandle() call actually being executed?  When you breakpoint on the line, is 'com->id' the same value as was returned by the CreateFileA() call?  You have not, by any chance, already destroyed com at that time?  Also, what @HansPassant says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx):

> When an application is finished using the object handle returned by
>   CreateFile, use the **CloseHandle** function to close the handle. This not
>   only frees up system resources, but can have wider influence on things
>   like sharing the file or device and committing data to disk. Specifics
>   are noted within this topic as appropriate.

Comment: The problem was that I needed to close the handle everytime I read/write to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Use `GetLastError` to get the error code, and use the `FormatMessage` to get a human readable error description, or just simply Google the error code.

There are many reasons can cause the same error (`CreateFile` returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`), without the `GetLastError`, you will very hard to find out what is the real reason.